# Python memory footprint vs. heap size

Tags: python, memory-leaks, solr

I'm having some memory issues while using a python script to issue a large **solr** query.  I'm using the **solrpy** library to interface with the solr server.  The query returns approximately 80,000 records.  Immediately after issuing the query the python memory footprint as viewed through top balloons to ~190MB.

```
 PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND 
8225 root      16   0  193m 189m 3272 S  0.0 11.2   0:11.31 python
...
```

At this point, the heap profile as viewed through heapy looks like this:

```
Partition of a set of 163934 objects. Total size = 14157888 bytes.   
 Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Kind (class / dict of class)
     0  80472  49  7401384  52   7401384  52 unicode
     1  44923  27  3315928  23  10717312  76 str
...
```

The unicode objects represent the unique identifiers of the records from the query.  One thing to note is that the total heap size is only 14MB while python is occupying 190MB of physical memory.  Once the variable storing the query results falls out of scope, the heap profile correctly reflects the garbage collection:

```
Partition of a set of 83586 objects. Total size = 6437744 bytes.
 Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Kind (class / dict of class)
     0  44928  54  3316108  52   3316108  52 str
```

However, the memory footprint remains unchanged:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 8225 root      16   0  195m 192m 3432 S  0.0 11.3   0:13.46 python
...
```

Why is there such a large disparity between python's physical memory footprint and the size of the python heap?

Comment: Is this behaviour reproducable for smaller queries also?

Comment: The physical memory footprint increases proportionately to the size of the query.

Answer (score 6):

Python allocates Unicode objects from the C heap. So when you allocate many of them (along with other malloc blocks), then release most of them except for the very last one, C malloc will not return any memory to the operating system, as the C heap will only shrink on the end (not in the middle). Releasing the last Unicode object will release the block at the end of the C heap, which then allows malloc to return it all to the system.

On top of these problems, Python also maintains a pool of freed unicode objects, for faster allocation. So when the last Unicode object is freed, it isn't returned to malloc right away, making all the other pages stuck.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're saying that the heapy output shows the contents of the python private heap.  The top output shows the total memory allocated to my process through the C API?  

If that is the case, can you suggest any techniques to ensure that python releases the raw memory back to the OS once the contents of that memory is no longer needed?

Comment: As Roberto says: use the latest Python version. If the problem does not go away, report a bug to bugs.python.org, preferably including a fix.

Comment: It seems that Python on Linux does not release freed memory back to the operating system. More info here: http://python.dzone.com/articles/diagnosing-memory-leaks-python

Answer (score 3):

CPython implementation only exceptionally free's allocated memory. This is a widely known bug, but it isn't receiving much attention by CPython developers. The recommended workaround is to "fork and die" the process that consumes lots RAM.

Comment: Is this the bug that Roberto is referring to that has been fixed in 2.5?  Or is this bug known to still exist?

Comment: hruske, are you really sure about what you are saying? I have no experience of such bug, and I have also no knowledge about it from the python bug tracker.

Comment: From my experience, yes. For example, processing large amounts of data in a deamon will leave you afterwards with a large amount of malloc'd RAM, which will then after some time be swapped out and very likely not free'd. However, this may not be because of gc bug but rather because of a circular reference. Try checking here http://www.lshift.net/blog/2008/11/14/tracing-python-memory-leaks if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

What version of python are you using?
I am asking because [older version of CPython did not release the memory](http://evanjones.ca/python-memory.html) and this was fixed in Python 2.5.

Comment: I was using CPython 2.4 when I came across the link that you posted.  Unfortunately, I'm experiencing the same behavior when I run the scripts in 2.6.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the updated version? I had a similar issue once, and in the end I discovered that the server was still using an older python version.

Comment: I running on a CentOS machine where 2.4 is the default version.  I installed 2.6 just to test this issue.  I'm running my scripts explicitly calling python2.6.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented hruske's advice of "fork and die".  I'm using os.fork() to execute the memory intensive section of code in a child process, then I let the child process exit.  The parent process executes an os.waitpid() on the child so that only one thread is executing at a given time.

If anyone sees any pitfalls with this solution, please chime in.

Comment: os.fork() can get messy in multi-threaded apps.
fork "duplicates" the whole process memory, yet keeps only the main thread running. so any lock you entered in other threads, might deadlock your forked app