# Python memory consumption on Linux: physical and virtual memory are growing while the heap size remains the same

Tags: python, linux, memory-consumption

I'm working on the some kind of a system service (actually it's just a log parser) written in Python. This program should work continuously for a long time (hopefully I mean days and weeks without failures and needs of restart). That's why I am concerned about memory consumption.

I put together different information about process memory usage from different sites into one simple function:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from pprint import pprint
from guppy import hpy
from datetime import datetime
import sys
import os
import resource
import re

def debug_memory_leak():
    #Getting virtual memory size 
    pid = os.getpid()
    with open(os.path.join("/proc", str(pid), "status")) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    _vmsize = [l for l in lines if l.startswith("VmSize")][0]
    vmsize = int(_vmsize.split()[1])

    #Getting physical memory size  
    pmsize = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss

    #Analyzing the dynamical memory segment - total number of objects in memory and heap size
    h = hpy().heap()
    if __debug__:
        print str(h)
    m = re.match(
        "Partition of a set of ([0-9]+) objects. Total size = ([0-9]+) bytes(.*)", str(h))
    objects = m.group(1)
    heap = int(m.group(2))/1024 #to Kb

    current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    data = (current_time, objects, heap, pmsize, vmsize)
    print("\t".join([str(d) for d in data]))
```

This function has been used to study the dynamics of the memory consumption of my long-playing process, and I still cannot explain its behavior. You can see that the heap size and total amount of the objects did not changed while the physical and virtual memory increased by 11% and 1% during these twenty minutes.

**UPD:** The process has been working for almost 15 hours by this moment. The heap is still the same, but the physical memory increased sixfold and the virtual memory increased by 50%. The curve is seem to be linear excepting the strange outliers at 3:00 AM:

> Time Obj      Heap    PhM    VM
>
> 19:04:19  31424   3928    5460    143732
>
> 19:04:29  30582   3704    10276   158240
>
> 19:04:39  30582   3704    10372   157772
>
> 19:04:50  30582   3709    10372   157772
>
> 19:05:00  30582   3704    10372   157772
>
> (...)
>
> 19:25:00  30583   3704    11524   159900
>
> 09:53:23  30581   3704    62380   210756

I wonder what is going on with the address space of my process. The constant size of heap suggests that all of the dynamical objects are deallocated correctly. But I have no doubt that growing memory consumption will affect the sustainability of this life-critical process in the long run.

[image]

Could anyone clarify this issue please? Thank you.

(I use RHEL 6.4, kernel 2.6.32-358 with Python 2.6.6)

Comment: How does the chart look when you run for several hours instead of 20 minutes?

Comment: Oh, possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1194416/691859

Comment: @2rs2ts, thanks for your reply. I'll update the chart tomorrow when I come to work :)

Comment: @2rs2ts, the process was working the all night long, the memory is still growing.

Comment: Okay, that tells a different story than just a few minutes, so thanks for measuring that and sharing. Anyway, I'm not sure about whether this applies, but I saw [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23385471/a-simple-hello-word-needs-10g-virtual-memory-on-a-64-bit-machine-vs-1g-at-32-b) on programmers (it's migrated to SO now) about virtual memory usage in a simple "Hello World" java program. The heap size staying consistent tells me that you shouldn't have to worry, but the physical memory increasing worries says otherwise. I hope someone else can give a definitive answer.

Comment: Perhaps the stack is steadily increasing and you're not aware of it? (I'm not sure if that question even applies in this case, but...) You can take a look at the stack using [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1156048/691859), so maybe you could log the number of lines in the formatted stack and see if it grows.

Comment: Is python's memory space becoming fragmented, or does python just never release any memory?

Answer (score 8):

Without knowing what your program is doing, this might help.

I came across this article when working on a project a while back:
http://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2013/08/03/diagnosing-memory-leaks-python.html
Which says, "Long running Python jobs that consume a lot of memory while running may not return that memory to the operating system until the process actually terminates, even if everything is garbage collected properly."

I ended up using the multiprocessing module to have my project fork a separate process and return when it needed to do work, and I haven't noticed any memory issues since.

That or try it in Python 3.3 http://bugs.python.org/issue11849

Comment: Unfortunately, the library that I'm using (auparse - goes with the auditd in Linux) is still not ported to the 3rd branch.